# JPA, Hibernate, Oracle 19c la secuencia avanza de dos en dos

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, insert

El problema aparece al migrar la BBDD de datos principal del proyecto de PostgreSql a Oracle 19c.

En Oracle se han creado secuencias del mismo nombre que ya existían en PostgreSql y triggers para que los id de las tablas tomaran el valor de la secuencia, funcionando correctamente en inserciones sql directas sobre BBDD.
El problema aparece al insertar desde java, usando JPA + Hiberante, indicar que tanto el avance de la secuencia (esta correctamente de uno en uno ) y la definición el id (detallo)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="users_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="users_seq", sequenceName="users_seq", allocationSize=1)     
@Column(name="user_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
```

Como se puede ver allocationSize=1, depurando el valor tras la insercción era una unidad por debajo de la que aparece insertada en BBDD.

Tras revisar lo obvio, que la secuencia avanzara de uno en uno, que allocationSize=1, cambiando
@SequenceGenerator de Javax por su equivalente de hibernate @GenericGenerator, también cambiando la forma de la generación de ID, de Sequence a Identity. Nada siempre en BBDD un valor +1 al que debería y al que JPA indicaba. (de dos en dos)

En la secuencia esta fiajdo el incremnento en 1 "INCREMENT BY 1"

Indicar que la inserción se realizaba mediante persit como puede verse a continuación

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "XXXXXXX")
private EntityManager manager;
```

En el método de alta se invoca el manager y persiste así

```
manager.persist(newuser);
```

¿Alguna idea, dado que en PostgreSql este código, tanto para la definición de Entidades y su secuencias (no se usaba SERIAL) funcionaba perfectamente.

Comment: solo para descartar estaría bien que indicaras adicionalmente cual es la versión del conector que usas